# How to find an average date/time in the array of DateTime values

Tags: c#, datetime, average

If I have an array of DateTime values:

```
List<DateTime> arrayDateTimes;
```

What's the way to find the average DateTime among them?

For instance, if I have:

```
2003-May-21 15:00:00
2003-May-21 19:00:00
2003-May-21 20:00:00
```

the average should be:

```
2003-May-21 18:00:00
```

Comment: +1 nice question. See this http://42zone.blogspot.com/2011/09/c-how-to-calculate-multiple-datetime.html, just tested it and works with over 38,000 dates.

Comment: note that some answers preserve timezone information and others do not ..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have large list you can use below method

```
var count = dates.Count;
double temp = 0D;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    temp += dates[i].Ticks / (double)count;
}
var average = new DateTime((long)temp);
```

Comment: It will throw overflow exception with large list.

Comment: **dates[i].Ticks / count** will return 0 if count > Ticks

Comment: Console.WriteLine(ticks / (ticks + 1));
            Console.WriteLine(ticks / long.MaxValue);
What would be printed ?

Comment: @Uzzy: Ticks are measured as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that elapsed since Jan 1, 1601. I don't know the word for such number but this is how it may look `635,047,830,427,420,548` so I don't think `count` will be greater than `Ticks`.

Comment: @Damith: `System.Int64` **is** an integer.

Answer (score 9):

This shouldn't overflow, it does assume the datetimes are ordered though:

```
var first = dates.First().Ticks;
var average = new DateTime(first + (long) dates.Average(d => d.Ticks - first));
```

The above does in fact overflow with larger lists and larger gaps. I think you could use seconds for better *range*. (again, sorted first) Also, this might not be the most performant method, but still completed with 10M dates relatively quickly for me. Not sure if it's easier to read or not, YYMV.

```
var first = dates.First();
var average = first.AddSeconds(dates.Average(d => (d - first).TotalSeconds));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Ticks is of type long. A future tick, minus a past tick, will give a relatively small number, and shouldn't ever have the possibility of overflowing.

Comment: @c00000fd no problem, glad to help with a solution.

Comment: This would again result in overflowing, with large list of dates, test it with `4704` dates in the list.

Comment: Tested and this gives `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

Comment: It does indeed overflow with fairly large lists, which have fairly large gaps. I have updated with an answer using seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Source: Taken from [Here](http://42zone.blogspot.com/2011/09/c-how-to-calculate-multiple-datetime.html) and modified a bit.

```
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
//Add dates
for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) //days
    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) //month
        for (int k = 1900; k <= 2013; k++) //year
            dates.Add(new DateTime(k, j, i, 1, 2, 3)); //over 38000 dates
```

Then you can do:

```
var averageDateTime = DateTime
                            .MinValue
                            .AddSeconds
                            ((dates
                                 .Sum(r => (r - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds))
                                     / dates.Count);
Console.WriteLine(averageDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Output in: `1956-Dec-29 06:09:25`

Originally the code from the article was like:

```
double totalSec = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
{
    TimeSpan ts = dates[i].Subtract(DateTime.MinValue);
    totalSec += ts.TotalSeconds;
}
double averageSec = totalSec / dates.Count;
DateTime averageDateTime = DateTime.MinValue.AddSeconds(averageSec);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
var count = dates.Count;
double temp = 0D;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    temp += dates[i].Ticks / (double)count;
}
var average = new DateTime((long)temp);
```

is Wrong.  Average=(x1 + x2 + ... xN) / N not (x1/N + x2/N + ... xN/N)

Try:

```
var avg=new DateTime((long)dates.Select(d => d.Ticks).Average());
```

Comment: This can cause arithmetic overflow if averaging over a large number as the sum (before dividing by N) can exceed long.MaxValue. The alternative method is more robust.

Comment: Actually `(x1 + x2 + ... xN) / N` and `(x1/N + x2/N + ... xN/N)` is equal. It's just a different way of writing. (but as @BrendanHill wrote the second method is more robust)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>(){
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 17, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 17, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 17, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 19, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 20, 0, 0), new DateTime(2003, 5, 21, 16, 0, 0),
    };

        var averageDate = dates.Average();

        Console.WriteLine(averageDate);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static long Average(this IEnumerable<long> longs)
    {
        long count = longs.Count();

        long mean = 0;

        foreach (var val in longs)
        {
            mean += val / count;
        }

        return mean;
    }

    public static DateTime Average(this IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
    {
        return new DateTime(dates.Select(x => x.Ticks).Average());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm obviously not doing it with 3 values :) Your method will overflow with about 20 dates.

Comment: @c00000fd: 40 datetimes and an extension method after, there's no more overflow.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Although it's been already suggested by @Damith above.

Answer (score 0):

Using double seconds instead of long ticks will avoid overflow on any real-world inputs - extension method here.

```
    public static DateTime Average(this IEnumerable<DateTime> elements)
    {
        if (elements == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elements));
        }
        var enumerated = elements.ToArray(); //so we don't iterate a potentially one-use stream multiple times.
        if (!enumerated.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Average of 0 elements is undefined", nameof(elements));
        }

        var epoch = enumerated.Min();
        var secondsSinceEpoch = enumerated.Select(d => (d - epoch).TotalSeconds).ToArray();
        var n = secondsSinceEpoch.LongLength;
        double totalSecondsSinceEpoch = secondsSinceEpoch.Sum();
        return epoch.AddSeconds(totalSecondsSinceEpoch / n);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void HugeDateAverage_DoesntThrow()
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1900,1,1);
        try
        {
            var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000_000)
             .Select(i => epoch.AddSeconds(i));
            var result = dates.Average();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

If you really want to get degenerate, you could detect the overflow and recurse on half the elements, being careful with the odd-N case. This is untested but here's the idea:

```
    //NOT FOR ACTUAL USE - JUST FOR FUN
    public static DateTime AverageHuge(this IEnumerable<DateTime> elements)
    {
        if (elements == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elements));
        }
        var enumerated = elements.ToArray(); //so we don't iterate a potentially one-use stream multiple times.
        if (!enumerated.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Average of 0 elements is undefined", nameof(elements));
        }

        var epoch = enumerated.Min();
        var secondsSinceEpoch = enumerated.Select(d => (d - epoch).TotalSeconds).ToArray();
        var n = secondsSinceEpoch.LongLength;
        if (n > int.MaxValue)
        {
            //we could actually support more by coding Take+Skip with long arguments.
            throw new NotSupportedException($"only int.MaxValue elements supported");
        }

        try
        {
            double totalSecondsSinceEpoch = secondsSinceEpoch.Sum(); //if this throws, we'll have to break the problem up
            //otherwise we're done.
            return epoch.AddSeconds(totalSecondsSinceEpoch / n);
        }
        catch (OverflowException) { } //fall out of this catch first so we don't throw from a catch block

        //Overengineering to support large lists whose totals would be too big for a double.
        //recursively get the average of each half of values.
        int pivot = (int)n / 2;
        var avgOfAvgs = (new []
        {
            enumerated.Take(pivot).AverageHuge(),
            enumerated.Skip(pivot).Take(pivot).AverageHuge()
        }).AverageHuge();
        if (pivot * 2 == n)
        {   // we had an even number of elements so we're done.
            return avgOfAvgs;
        }
        else
        {   //we had an odd number of elements and omitted the last one.
            //it affects the average by 1/Nth its difference from the average (could be negative)
            var adjust = ((enumerated.Last() - avgOfAvgs).TotalSeconds) / n;
            return avgOfAvgs.AddSeconds(adjust);
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these solutions involving long were causing an overflow.

I propose:

```
public static DateTime DateTimeAverage(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates) => DateTime.FromOADate(dates.Select(d => d.ToOADate()).Average());
```

Answer (score -1):

The [answer by neouser99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683526/5724756) is correct. It prevents overflow by doing an incremental average.

However, this [answer by David Jiménez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33169675/5724756) is wrong because it doesn't handle overflow and his misunderstanding on the formula.

> Average=(x1 + x2 + ... xN) / N not (x1/N + x2/N + ... xN/N)

These are the same formula. It's simple math using the distributive property:

```
2(x + y) = 2x + 2y
```

The average formula is the same as multiplying your sum by 1/N. Or multiplying each individual X by 1/N and adding them together.

```
1/n (x1 + x2 + ... xn)
```

which by the distributive property becomes:

```
x1/n + x2/n + ... xn/n
```

Here's some [info on the distributive property](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/numbprop.htm)

His answer is also bad because it doesn't prevent overflow like the accepted answer.

I would have commented on his reply, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21249171)

Comment: I added an edit: I clarified why the accepted answer is correct which doesn't explain anything (because it prevents overflow) and why another answer with a positive score is wrong. So I believe this does answer the original question.