# Calculating the average of different dates in different years

Tags: c#, asp.net, c, vb.net, excel

I need to calculate the average the following observed dates:

```
1/7/2010
15/7/2011
17/6/2012
3/7/2013
```

How can I do that in asp.net or any other language. If there is any formula to do that.

Comment: `c#`, `c` and `vb.net`? That's not a good way to ask. Did you try _anything_ by the way?

Comment: What result would you expect? How can dates be averaged?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to convert it to Ticks (this will convert it to `System.Int64`) and then do the average of them all.

See the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683441/643761

Comment: this work on dates in the same year .not different years .

Comment: You are wrong. Read about ticks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx. `"The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001, which represents DateTime.MinValue."`

Comment: Thank you Simcha Khabinsky. I understand.