# How to get average of duration updated in a <td> using jquery or Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I get average of all duration listed in .
Duration is the result of CreatedDateTime - EndDateTime. So John works on 10 tickets, CreatedDateTime and enddateimt is updated for all tickets he worked on. Now in view it shows me CreatedDateTime, EndDateTime, and Time John spent for each ticket. So as he worked on 10 tickets there are 10 Duration entry showing for John like this
00:20:30 and so on.
Now I am looking for get an average of all these 10 entried listed in  and show them on the View.

How can this be done? Help is much appreciated

1. Mytickets View td I am needing help on

```
<td>
   <span class="test">@(string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", item.ChatEndDateTime - item.ChatStartDateTime, new { @class = "res" }))</span>
</td>
```

Using Asp.Net MVC Entity Frame Work. I guess this can be done using jQuery, I tried few codes, but no success

Comment: If you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683412/how-to-find-an-average-date-time-in-the-array-of-datetime-values

Comment: @VarunSetia appreciate your response, tried but not getting what I am looking for.